# Reading a text file into MATLAB and storing as two separate arrays

Tags: arrays, matlab, file, text

I need to be able to take this:

2.8 7.23 3.64 5.91 9.14 4.17 3.63

2.2 7.53 2.20 10.00 3.28 3.09 7.22

1.1 3.64 7.85 5.15 2.78 7.39 9.15

3.6 3.49 9.99 2.40 7.68 4.53 4.97

2.8 2.60 8.82 5.46 10.00 10.00 7.93

3.5 6.33 4.98 10.00 8.11 2.99 10.00

2.5 6.90 7.35 10.00 10.00 9.93 10.00

1.0 2.05 3.75 5.28 2.34 7.61 9.80

3.8 4.61 7.32 10.00 8.19 2.01 4.19

2.2 5.43 4.12 8.29 5.61 7.33 8.33

3.2 2.13 8.84 2.72 3.40 4.12 9.13

1.4 9.01 5.88 8.79 3.28 7.87 2.03

Which is saved into a text file say, nums.txt, and save it to an array in Matlab. However I have to save the first column as a [x by 1] array, and then the rest as a separate array. Sorry if that doesnt makes sense. But I just can't figure it out. Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

I managed to get the column array saved by using this:

```
diveData = fopen(dive_data.txt');

degDiff = textscan(diveData, '%f %*[^\n]');

degDiff = degDiff{:};
```

However, I can't get the rest of the array to work so I'm not sure what to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, read in all of your data at once using [`textread`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/textread.html).  If you do it like this, then you will read all of your data as a single 1D array. To fix this, you'll need to [`reshape`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html) the array so that you have a 7 column array.  Note that MATLAB reads in data by columns, so you'll need to transpose your matrix when you're finished.

After this, extract the first column to put this into one array, then use the rest of the content and place this into another array.  In other words:

```
f = textread('nums.txt', '%f');
vals = reshape(f, 7, []).';
oneColumn = vals(:,1);
otherStuff = vals(:,2:end);
```

`oneColumn` will be the first column you want, while `otherStuff` will be the other columns.  When you run this code, this is what I get with your data:

```
oneColumn =

    2.8000
    2.2000
    1.1000
    3.6000
    2.8000
    3.5000
    2.5000
    1.0000
    3.8000
    2.2000
    3.2000
    1.4000

otherStuff =

    7.2300    3.6400    5.9100    9.1400    4.1700    3.6300
    7.5300    2.2000   10.0000    3.2800    3.0900    7.2200
    3.6400    7.8500    5.1500    2.7800    7.3900    9.1500
    3.4900    9.9900    2.4000    7.6800    4.5300    4.9700
    2.6000    8.8200    5.4600   10.0000   10.0000    7.9300
    6.3300    4.9800   10.0000    8.1100    2.9900   10.0000
    6.9000    7.3500   10.0000   10.0000    9.9300   10.0000
    2.0500    3.7500    5.2800    2.3400    7.6100    9.8000
    4.6100    7.3200   10.0000    8.1900    2.0100    4.1900
    5.4300    4.1200    8.2900    5.6100    7.3300    8.3300
    2.1300    8.8400    2.7200    3.4000    4.1200    9.1300
    9.0100    5.8800    8.7900    3.2800    7.8700    2.0300
```